# Cloud Debugger API will be shutdown May 31, 2023

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, bitbucket

I noticed that Cloud Debugger [API](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs) will be shutdown May 31, 2023, so I went to the console and disabled the API for my Google Appengine. No surprise, but I now get an error in my logs. I don't use the Cloud debugger (that I'm aware of), so what is causing the error:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://clouddebugger.googleapis.com/v2/controller/debuggees/register
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1924)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.google.devtools.cdbg.debuglets.java.GcpHubClient.registerDebuggee(Unknown Source)
```

None of my Java 11 code, POM, Appengine-web.xml or web.xml reference the API, so not sure what is calling the API, so I can switch off the requests to the API. Hope you can help.

Thanks
Tim

Comment: From looking deeper into the logs and also here: https://console.cloud.google.com/debug?project=XXX It looks like Bitbucket is making the API request. My gmail account is the same for bitbucket and GCP, and somehow they are linked. Any idea how to disconnect them?

Comment: You need to login to id.atlassian.com(https://id.atlassian.com/login) and navigate to Manage profile → Security section (https://id.atlassian.com/login?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fid.atlassian.com%2Fmanage-profile%2Fsecurity). Unless your domain is managed by Google, you'll be able to set your password there.

Another way is to logout from your Atlassian account, then use the recovery form(https://id.atlassian.com/login/resetpassword).

Comment: I think the Atlassian/BitBucket isn't the problem. I have removed all references to .git etc. in the war file and even set the source in my appengine to be local files - So I don't think it is this :-(

Comment: Of my set of Appengine projects, I have noticed that it only gives the IOException for my Java 11. For Java 8, I don't get the issue. When migrating to Java 11, I am still using the "Legacy bundled services", so still need my appengine-web.xml and have add to add: <app-engine-apis>true</app-engine-apis>. So why does adding this kick off the https://clouddebugger.googleapis.com. Any more help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To stop these error logs, add the Cloud Debugger Agent role to the service account. You can modify the default service account and remove the “Editor” role and is using this as the service account for App Engine.

Comment: Thanks, but sadly this didn't work. I added the extra role to the Service account and even removed the Editor role, only leaving the Cloud Datastore User.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be fixed. I'm guessing that Google has done something on their side to stop these error. The API was due to be Deprecated on May 31st, and yesterday I noticed that it has finally been marked as such in the API list. So now when I disable it from my list of APIs in Google Cloud Console GUI, I no longer get the error mentioned above. Strange, but I'm happy as I can now continue to migrate my projects to Java 11.